# Is my random generator not working, or is there an error with how I am deciding whether a human/skeleton hits their opponent?

Tags: c++, random

Either way, if I put in the same amount of humans and zombies each time I get the same result. I think it might be a problem with my other code because when I change the varibles partaining to the the human/zombie strenth the results still end the same. But my friend had a similar program and his problem was with his random number generator, and I've never used mt19937 before. Here is my program. The user is supposed to input the number of zombies then skeletons, and the program is supposed to use a random number generator to decide which team wins and by how much. Help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

//Human Specifications
float humanAttack = 0.8f;
float humanDamage = 10.0f;
float maxHumanHealth = 15.0f;
float currentHumanHealth = maxHumanHealth;
int humanNumber;

//Zombie Specifications
float zombieAttack = 0.5f;
float zombieDamage = 15.0f;
float maxZombieHealth = 10.0f;
float currentZombieHealth = maxZombieHealth;
int zombieNumber;

char turn = 'H';
int attackResult;

int main() {

    mt19937 randomGenerator(time(NULL));
    //default_random_engine randomGenerator(time(NULL));
    uniform_real_distribution<float> attack(0.0f, 1.0f);

    //Setting Numbers
    cout << "~*~*~*~*-Humans VS Zombies-*~*~*~*~" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Set the number of humans: ";
    cin >> humanNumber;
    cout << endl << "Set the number of zombies: ";
    cin >> zombieNumber;

    while ((zombieNumber >0) && (humanNumber >0)) {

        //Dice Roll
        attackResult = attack(randomGenerator);

        //Humans Turn
        if (turn == 'H') {
            if (attackResult < humanAttack) {
                currentZombieHealth = currentZombieHealth - humanAttack;
                if (currentZombieHealth <= 0) {
                    zombieNumber --;
                    currentZombieHealth = maxZombieHealth;
                }
            }
            turn = 'Z';
        }

        //Zombies Turn
        else {
            if (attackResult < zombieAttack) {
                currentHumanHealth = currentHumanHealth - zombieAttack;
                if (currentHumanHealth <= 0) {
                    humanNumber --;
                    currentHumanHealth = maxHumanHealth;
                }
            }
            turn = 'H';
        }


    }

    cout << endl << "[The noise of battle...]" << endl << endl << endl;
    cout << "BATTLE IS OVER" << endl << endl;

    if (zombieNumber > 0) {
        cout << "The zombies have won the battle!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "The humans have won the battle!" << endl;
    }
    cout << "There are " << humanNumber << " humans and " << zombieNumber << " zombies left alive." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Um.. `attackResult` is an `int`. That hard-earned `float` your generator is making is going to be terribly worthless. when it gets truncated.

Comment: This is a typical example where a small bug has  enormous terrifying consequences. Sometimes rockets explode and in this case zombie apocalypse! I'll go pack my bags now and hide

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler is likely warning about the following line:

```
attackResult = attack(randomGenerator);
```

You should be seeing something like:

> truncation of float to integer

Pay attention to compiler warnings they are free bug catchers.

Your problem is that `attackResult` is an integer so your floating point number between `0.0` and `1.0` is always truncated to an integer of `0`.